# Updates to admin.py not reflected in the django admin page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm building a django app and the django admin page doesn't seem to be reflecting the changes I make to admin.py. For example if I want to exclude some fields, or customizing the admin change list, nothing changes in the actual page. The only thing that seems to be reflected properly is the fact that I can register the models, and they will show up.

Here's my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Form, Biuletyn, Ogloszenie, Album

class FormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('img',)

class BiuletynAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'date')

class OgloszenieAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name', 'date', 'upload')

admin.site.register(Form)
admin.site.register(Biuletyn)
admin.site.register(Ogloszenie)
admin.site.register(Album)
```

P.S. Please ignore the weird model names. The site is actually in a different language :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you register your `ModelAdmin`:

```
admin.site.register(Form, FormAdmin)
admin.site.register(Biuletyn, BiuletynAdmin)
admin.site.register(Ogloszenie, OgloszenieAdmin)
```

This how to register your `Models`:

```
admin.site.register(Album)
```

For more details you may refer to Django official documentation at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects

Answer (score 1):

### Add admin_class

So for example for the Form model:

```py
admin.site.register(Form, admin_class=FormAdmin)
```